# not able to locate gradle.properties in toolbox

Tags: docker, gradle

I'm trying to run ./gradlew build command, which has artifactory_contextUrl property used in build.gradle file.

gradlew.properties is located in C:\Users\XXX.gradle folder, when I build the project in windows Intellij it takes the gradle.properties file in user folder and so gets the contexturl and everything is fine but,

when I try to build the project in docker toolbox it couldnt find it.
Toolbox starts with some location in C folder.

I tried with placing gradle.properties at the same level as build.gradle it works fine in toolbox. Eventually I dont want to keep the gradle.properties at buils.gradle level

What should I do? Does any one has any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I guess the docker toolbox (whatever it is, I don't know it) does run with another user account and thus does not find your `gradle.properties` file in your user directory.

The file is actually called `gradle.properties`, isn't it? In your question you use `gradlew.properties` and `gradle.properties` and only the latter is valid.

To solve your problem you can either make sure the `gradle.properties` is also in the users home directory that is used in the docker toolbox. To find out which directory this is, you can run Gradle with `-d` and search for `Gradle user home`, there it tells you which directory is the one where the `gradle.properties` is expected.

Alternatively you can use `-P artifactory_contextUrl=asdf` to set the property from the commandline, or use the system property `org.gradle.project.artifactory_contextUrl` or environment variable `ORG_GRADLE_PROJECT_artifactory_contextUrl` to set the project property.